# How tall was an average person in ancient Israel?

Tags: archaeology, israel

As has long been known, Goliath's height wasn't as impressive as most people would believe. However, I've been thinking; even at the lowest estimates he still would've been taller than an average even by modern standards. Also, as we know, average height has increased over time (previously attributed mainly to advances in medicine, though now believed to be due to growth hormones being injected into the farm animals we consume).

Given this, is it possible that Goliath's height (regardless of whether he existed at all) was more impressive by the standards of ancient peoples? Of course, King David's historicity is dubious, so its hard to attribute an exact date to when Goliath may have lived. Still, it is possible his 7 or so feet may have been far more imposing to the people who originally wrote about him than he would be to us today? The point I'm making is he may have constituted a giant when that book was first written, he just wouldn't by modern standards.

Comment: Isn't 'giant' always relative? A giant mouse just has to be bigger than other mice, it doesn't have to tower over a human. So as long as Goliath was taller than the people around him, he _was_ a giant. The exact measurements wouldn't matter.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  What's wrong with the answers on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_appearance_of_Jesus).   Recent research undermines the assertion in your first sentence.

Comment: To be clear, was that directed at me or people replying? Your link is about deleting posts, which doesn't appear to have happened here.

Comment: It is worth also looking into Saul (the Jewish King fighting Goliath), who was elected the king because he was the tallest. When David volunteers to fight Goliath, he is put into Saul's armor, which turns out to be way too big. For more fun account I recommend [*God Knows*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_Knows_(novel)) by Joseph Heller (the author of Catch-22).

Answer (score 2):

**We don't really know**.

I've tried looking for sources, but people online will tell you anything from a seemingly puny 5'1" to a more reasonable [5'5"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34272753). There's no lack of guesses here, but we simply don't know definitively.

While we don't really have great sources for the average height of 2nd Millennium Jews and Philistines, **we do actually have sources for [Goliath's height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath#Goliath%27s_height)**. Both the Dead Sea Scrolls and the earliest Jewish ("Old Testament") texts list it at a cubit measurement that works out to 6'9" (205 cm). That would put him right between the [modern average height](https://www.thehoopsgeek.com/average-nba-height/) of an NBA power forward and an NBA center.

Comment: I will say that *if* the speculation that [the Philistines were Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistines#Scholarly_consensus) happens to be true, it's possible they had a bigger average height due to dietary issues. Particularly childhood calcium intake through cow's milk. Most modern Semitic-speakers are lactose intolerant. There's far too much fuzz in that statement to be anything more than an interesting possibility though. Anyway, as a Christian myself, **why** Goliath was big isn't really the point of the story.

Comment: Are there no skeletons from that time? Are there no surviving pieces of armor, or doorways, or other such artifacts that could indicate height? How could it be possible to 'not know'? Is the archeological record really that scant?

Comment: That's 2 meter and 5 centimeter. I know you're American, but can you add that to your answer? 6'9'' is a bit cryptic.

Comment: If you're used to SAE, 2 meters and 5 cm is just as unfathomable. I particularly hate when measurements are given only in centimeters. I can't even imagine what x centimeters look like.

Comment: @Jos - Call it a hunch. The question itself had an "American" feel to it, so I used units (both Imperial and "basketball players") we'd be familiar with. That being said, there is an "edit" button there if you have the converted numbers, and think they should be added. Now that you bring it up, it does seem like a metric conversion would be useful info to add for others.

Comment: No problem, I just did that. I wanted to know if you would approve of it.

Comment: @user8600 - *Why* I couldn't find more is another question. I did a quick check, and it looks like Western Semitic people of that era (Jews and Phoenicians) preferred tomb burials (this is well-attested in Biblical sources too). Such remains don't tend to preserve well. It probably doesn't help that they tend to be considered holy sites today. There was a 9th century BC Philistine cemetery discovered recently, but the remains when DNA tested proved mostly similar to neighboring Semitic peoples, with just a bit of European admixture. So we'd perhaps need an earlier cemetery.

Comment: @user8600 the Society of Automotive Engineers makes standards for tools and hardware.  They do not define the units of measurement.